# Magento 1.9.1. CE : Disabling core_url_rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, url-rewrite, product-urls

I'm looking for an effective solution to disable completely `core_url_rewrite` table. I've disabled the Url Rewriting on the backend, but each time i add or update a product, an `url_key` is written to this table.

I don't need this feature.

Anybody have a solution to skip this step when I **add/update product** or when a execute the reindexation.

Comment: Have you tried to set the index mode to "manual update"?

Comment: You know that product `url_key` requires URL Rewrite Management to work and you are okay with your product URLs being something like `/catalog/product/view/id/1/`?

Comment: Saying that you don't need this feature is essentially saying that you won't depend on search engines routing traffic to your store...why do you think that's the case?  Are you concerned about a performance impact of leaving it enabled?

Comment: Seo is less important for b2b only sites or sites with login protected catalog. So yeah, it's entirely possible to not need the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling URL rewriting in the backend refers to something else, namely web server rewrites. This means, without them, URLs are in the form

```
example.com/index.php/url_key
```

instead of

```
example.com/url_key
```

It is not intended to disable the catalog rewrite feature, but if you want to prevent the index from being written, you can rewrite the model `catalog/indexer_url` and override `reindexAll()` and `_processEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)` with empty methods.